# Phonegap remote chrome debugging white screen only

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm trying to inspect my phonegap webviews.

- I have enabled "developer mode" in my phone.
- It is plugged in USB
- It is plugged and visible on chrome://inspect/#devices

[image: chrome://inspect/#devices]

But when I click on inspect, I get a white screen, without further explanation:

[image: White screen]

Any idea? Is there a way to debug this? All I find on internet are version issues, but as far as I'm concerned, I feel like I'm up-to-date.

Using:

- Android 7.0 (Samsung A3 2017)
- Phonegap cli-6.5.0
- Chrome Android 65.0.3325.109
- Chrome Desktop 64.0.3282.167

Comment: You now have to manually navigate to `chrome://inspect` to get to the inspect tab. [See here](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/) A new tab with the Webview Debugging Tool will open. Once opened, make sure that `"Discover USB devices"` is checked.

Comment: That's what I have done and this is what gives me the blank screen... Yes, `Discover USB devices is checked`...

Comment: `WebView` debugging must be enabled from within your application. To enable `WebView` debugging check you have set the static  method `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` to true:
    `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`
I assume your `WebView` app is already running, and is not crashing on debug connect. If it is crashing check out your `WebView` version is > 39 *ish*, and not an old version from a custom ROM.